# Angular 5: how to make dynamically created components draggable with jsPlumb?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, draggable, jsplumb

I'm really struggling integrating `jsPlumb` into Angular.
I need to make some elements draggable, and I have no problem if I create a static HTML.
The problem comes when I create components dynamically, `jsPlumb` just seems to ignore those. I made sure to have the `id` properly set, but no luck.
As it is a bit difficult to explain I made an example, which you can find here: [example demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsplumb-ahnv9j)

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it calling the jsPlumb `draggable()` method in the `ngAfterViewInit` life cycle of the newly created component.
I'll post the link to the demo in case someone needs it: [jsPlumb demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsplumb-gdvtgi)